# Why my modal is not showing up after click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, popup, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to add a button that would open a modal where a user could fill their information. But I have a problem. I inserted a modal from bootstrap but it is not working. The button appears but after clicking nothing shows up. I have tried everything I know and also treid googling it but nothing on the internet helped. I am new in react and I don't know what is the problem and what I could do more. Here is a snippet from my code:

```js
function AddNew(props) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  return (
<>
  <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => setShow(true)} id="add-patient">
    Pridėti
  </Button>
  <Modal
    show={show}
    onHide={() => setShow(false)}
    dialogClassName="modal-90w"
    aria-labelledby="add-new"
  >
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title id="add-new">Custom Modal Styling</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
      <p>...</p>
    </Modal.Body>
  </Modal>
</>
  );
}
```

And this is all code: [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-clarke-nkt7h)

Please help me!

Comment: what i can say is that you must first verify if the modal is working or not by passing true on its show props. then next is check if show state are changed on click by console logging the result on rerender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example : https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-yonath-ui7q3

I just add `animation={false}` as a props to the `Modal` component to make it works (maybe some css files are missing to get the animation working):

```
<Modal
        show={show}
        onHide={() => setShow(false)}
        dialogClassName="modal-90w"
        aria-labelledby="add-new"
        animation={false}
      >
```

Edit: That is actually the reason, add bootstrap as a dependency and 
`import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";` in your code ([follow the installation instructions here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#installation))

Answer (score 0):

Please read [react-bootstrap introduction](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/getting-started/introduction/). You are missing bootstrap css which is required for react-bootstrap to work.

You need to install bootstrap

```
npm install bootstrap
```

and then import it in your `index.js` file

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```